# Websotrm не видит директив *ngIf и других Angular в автокомплите

Tags: javascript, angular, webstorm

Изучаю Angular и столкнулся с проблемой в webstorm, не работает автокомплит директив *ngIf *ngForm и другие.. Помогите разобраться.

[image: не работает автокомплит]